# Submitting an existing form with javascript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, phantomjs

I'm trying to browse a website using PhantomJS and need to submit a form at some point (without using jQuery). 
The submit button code is :

```
<button type="submit" class="submitButton">
   <img src="button.png">
</button>
```

When using the console, the element seems to be well identified :

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName('submitButton')
> <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
```

But when I try to submit it, I get the following error :

```
window.document.getElementsByClassName('submitButton').submit()
> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Am I using the method in a wrong way? I can't figure what's wrong. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use class name to get the element? When using `document.getElementsByClassName` they step in arrays `document.getElementsByClassName('Example')[0]` = > `document.getElementsByClassName('Example')[1]` => `document.getElementsByClassName('Example')[2]` Also, where is your form? Can you please display more relevant source code.

Comment: `undefined is not a function` means that the function/method you are trying to use does not exist.

Comment: If you want to submit a form when the user clicks the button then you will want to add an event listener to that button to trigger a function that will submit the form (Assuming that button isn't already in the form) *wherever this form maybe on the page*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit()` is a function of a `<form>` element, so just get the form instead of the button element.

For example:

```
<form id="myform" ... ></form>
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```